# Custom Payment Method Isn't validate before click Place order button

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.3.5-p2, custom-validation

Magento 2.3.5 version application using custom payment method module. This module refer from [code here](https://github.com/chris-huffman/LlamaCoin)

view/frontend/web/template/payment/llamacoin.html

```
    <!-- Render the native credit card form. -->
    <form class="form" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '-form'}">
        <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Payment/payment/cc-form' --><!-- /ko -->
    </form>

    <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button data-role="review-save"
                    type="submit"
                    data-bind="
                    attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                    enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                    click: placeOrder,
                    css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
                    "
                    class="action primary checkout"
                    disabled>
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[full code html file here](https://github.com/chris-huffman/LlamaCoin/blob/develop/view/frontend/web/template/payment/llamacoin.html)

view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/llamacoin.js

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form'
    ],
    function ($, Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'ClassyLlama_LlamaCoin/payment/llamacoin'
            },

            context: function() {
                return this;
            },

            getCode: function() {
                return 'classyllama_llamacoin';
            },

            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Checkout page show Payment method look like
[image]

This knockout js calling input field to html

```
 <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Payment/payment/cc-form' --><!-- /ko -->
```

**exception.log error show when click "Place Order"**

[2021-07-07 12:14:50] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /mnt/BLOCKSTORAGE/home/mydomain.com/applicationame/public_html/app/code/Pay360/Pay360payment/Model/Pay360.php on line 117 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /mnt/BLOCKSTORAGE/home/mydomain.com/applicationame/public_html/app/code/Pay360/Pay360payment/Model/Pay360.php on line 117 at /mnt/BLOCKSTORAGE/home/mydomain.com/applicationame/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []

Pay360.php line number 117 is

```
catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->debug($payment->getData(), $e->getMessage());
        }
```

Pay360payment\Model\Pay360.php (= LlamaCoin/Model/LlamaCoin.php )

```
public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        try {
            //check if payment has been authorized
            if (is_null($payment->getParentTransactionId())) {
                $this->authorize($payment, $amount);
            }

            //build array of payment data for API request.
            $request = [
                'capture_amount' => $amount,
                //any other fields, api key, etc.
            ];

            //make API request to credit card processor.
            $response = $this->makeCaptureRequest($request);

            //todo handle response

            //transaction is done.
            $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(1);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->debug($payment->getData(), $e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Sample Model file Full code here [enter link description here](https://github.com/chris-huffman/LlamaCoin/blob/develop/Model/LlamaCoin.php)

**My main issue** : incorrect data with "payment credit card number", "Card Verification Number" First time click
"Place order" show validation error
"an error occurred on the server. please try to place the order again after press next order place"

After again click Place order order succesfully place with incorrect data

Where will get input field ("payment credit card number","Card Verification Number" "expiration date") data customize with validation?

How can I validate and show error message using frontend or backend technology "payment credit card number", "expiration date" when customer click "Place Order" ?

if you provide any custom module or extension solve this issue,Please let me know,

Thanks for advance

Comment: any error in console?? before or after click on place order?

Comment: Please use this link - https://webkul.com/blog/add-cc-form-custom-payment-method-magento2/

Comment: @GohilRajesh Thanks for informing about error, I updated my question with var/log/exception.log details,Please check